# Using Xpath to parse html from a website

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

Currently I'm trying to use xpath to parse an html page from a website.

I need to get a result in the format:

> Date
>
> Time of the program : Program name

For example:

> OCT 18
>
> 1.00AM : Ye Hai Mohabbatein

I am using the following code to obtain this. But it is  working for 2 times.

```
<?php

$dat="Oct 18";
$ch = curl_init('http://www.starplus.in/schedule.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($page);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$n=0;
$shows = array();
$tables1 = $xpath->query("//td[@class='bdr_R_dot']");
$tables2 = $xpath->query("//div[@class='sech_div_bg']/table");
foreach ($tables1 as $table1) {
    $date = $xpath->query('./span[2]', $table1)->item(0)->nodeValue;  
    if($date==$dat){
        echo "<h1>$date</h1> <br>";
        foreach ($tables2 as $table2) {
            $time_slot = $xpath->query('./tr[1]/td/span', $table2)->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $show_name = $xpath->query('./tr[3]/td/span', $table2)->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $shows[] = array('time_slot' => $time_slot, 'show_name' => $show_name);      
            echo "$time_slot - $show_name <br/>";
        }
    }
}   

?>
```

I had done so many things but my code is executing for 2 times and the whole data is printing for two times. I will be thankful if anybody help me out in this issue.

Comment: "But it is working for 2 times." can you clarify on that?

Comment: The output is printing between the time slot 1.00 AM to 12.30 AM for twice.

Comment: can you show a snippet of the XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use that date to get the shows for that day. You can use that as a needle for that particular row table.

First target which row it will fall, and then get those rows. Example:

```
$dat = "Oct 18";
$ch = curl_init('http://www.starplus.in/schedule.aspx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($page);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$shows = array();
$node_list = $xpath->query("
    //td[@class='bdr_R_dot']/span[text() = '$dat']
    /parent::td/following-sibling::td
    /table/tr/td[3]/div/ul/li
");

echo $dat . '<br/><br/>';
foreach ($node_list as $el) {
    $time_slot = $xpath->query('./div/table/tr[1]/td/span', $el)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $show_name = $xpath->query('./div/table/tr[3]/td/span', $el)->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo "$time_slot : $show_name <br/>";
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LBHEgF)